# ScreenToWorldPoint returning wrong position even when given Z plane

Tags: unity

I have a NavMeshAgent placed on a character model. When I log `agent.transform.position` I get `(4.5, 0.1, 4.5)` which is correct (this is a 2.5d game and movement happens along the x and z axes).

I am trying to set up a script so that when I click a location on the screen, the character will turn to face that location.

The problem I'm facing is that the coordinates returned by `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` are not correct:

```
Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
mousePos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
Vector3 targetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

Debug.Log(agent.transform.position)
// Logs: (4.5, 0.1, 4.5)

Debug.Log(targetPos)
// Logs: (0.1, 16.7, 0.7)
```

In this example, I'm clicking on the same place as the agent but the targetPos is not nearly the same.

The y-axis  of `targetPos` is static (the same no matter where I click), which seems correct. However the values for x and z are not correct. How do I get the correct coordinates for a click?

*edit* I have this workaround, but I want to know how to solve the original question still:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 100, rotateTargets))
{
    Vector3 targetPos = hit.point;
    targetPos.y = agent.transform.position.y;
    Vector3 direction = (targetPos - agent.transform.position).normalized;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
    agent.transform.rotation = rotation; 
    agent.updateRotation = false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose the camera near plane for your z? This will tend to put all output points very close to your camera, rather than near the level geometry you're clicking on (since you'll usually have your near plane set much closer than the stuff you're drawing, so it doesn't get clipped out)

Comment: @DMGregory [it's part of the example given in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html). I tried replacing it with `agent.transform.position.y`, but if I do that then `targetPos` does not change at all no matter where my mouse is.

Comment: I should also mention, I did figure out a workaround using a raycast (see edit to question). However I still want to know how it can be tied to the mouse position without raycast.

Comment: A raycast is the correct solution when you want to find where a line from your eye through the mouse meets the terrain / other object in the game world. There are special cases you can solve for if you know a priori that you want a point on a particular plane or other geometric primitive, but without that a mouse position still leaves you with a degree of freedom that you need to fill in by specifying a depth along that camera-mouse ray.

Comment: @DMGregory Ok the main issue is I want the user to be able to click on empty space and still rotate to that position. Although I suppose I could just fill the empty space with an invisible plane. In the case without the raycast, though, I do provide the Z, so why is the position wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just at the z depth from the camera you told it, which was not the z position you wanted. The near plane is close to the camera, so no matter where the mouse is on screen, facing a point on the near plane means looking roughly toward the camera. You want to pass the depth value of your ground plane at that point, or just analytically calculate where the mouse ray hits your ground plane.

Comment: @DMGregory yes but as I mentioned, when I use `agent.transform.position.y` as the value for Z it doesn't work either

Comment: Right, because transform.position.y is also not the depth from the camera you want (unless your camera is at 0, 0, 0 and looking straight up). Try placing a sphere in the world at the place you want, and measuring its z depth from the camera. Watch how that value changes as you move the sphere around your ground plane to get a sense for what that parameter represents.

Comment: @DMGregory well there's the answer ... if I pass `Camera.main.position.y - agent.transform.position.y` as the value of `z`  for `ScreenToWorldPoint`, it works great. Thanks so much! Feel free to say this as an answer if you want (or I can do it myself)

Comment: That will depend on the orientation of your camera, which is a detail you'll likely want to add to your question.

Comment: @DMGregory it's pointing straight down the y axis. The thing I needed to understand was that the z parameter represents the distance from the camera, not the distance relative to zero.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use `Camera.main.position.y - agent.transform.position.y` as the value for z on `ScreenToWorldPoint`.

The reason is that the z argument in this case should be *the distance between the camera and the ground*, not *the ground's position relative to 0*.